# How can I get my menu bar app to launch at login?

Tags: swift, macos, launchd

I have made an app which shows your IP address in the menu bar. It has no dock icon and only runs in the menu bar.

I want this app to launch at login. I made a script which uses osascript to add the name.app to the login items, however I wan't to deploy this app and this isn't a proper solution.

I have tried following guides on creating a launchd launch agent/dameon however none of them show me how to get my app created in Xcode to create and copy a plist into ~/Library/LaunchAgents. I can make it manually, put it in place and it works, but how do I get a user (who just drags my app from a .dmg into the applications folder) to copy a launch agent too?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way of doing this now is to bundle the LoginItem inside the app bundle's Contents directory. You can then use [`SMLoginItemSetEnabled()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/SMLoginItem_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/SMLoginItemSetEnabled) to enable it.

Some more info and other options are available in the [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html).

Comment: Do you mean bundle the login item plist I made so I would include com.me.app.plist (which is the launch agent plist) inside the app bundle content directory?

Comment: It would be a full app bundle; you can see more info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html